# What is mixed damage in league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some skills do mixed damage. How can I tell what % is physical or magic from a death recap?
Does Liandrys Torment proc off mixed damage skills?

Comment: If you are wondering what to buy against it, you should look at the items of the champion that did the damage. Fizz for example does mixed damage, but his main damage is (most likely) Ability power.

Answer (score 7):

You can't tell the percentages, all Mixed damage means is that damage came in multiple types from one skill. Sometimes it's a combination of Physical and True (Irelia), Magical and True (Ahri), or Physical and Magical (Fizz).

[Liandry's Torment](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Liandry%27s_Torment) procs off of all activated abilities (Not on-hit effects), whether physical, magical, or True. It will work for abilities like Cho'Gath's Vorpal Spikes, as they trigger a spell activation on attack, rather than an on-hit effect. The same will hold true for [Rylai's Crystal Scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rylai%27s_Crystal_Scepter), so this item combination will work very well together.

Comment: Liandry's Torment says "Dealing spell damage applies a..."  This would imply that dealing physical damage in an ability would not active the ability, such as Caitlyn's skill, Piltover Peacemaker.  However you are saying that the tool tip is wrong?  And if so, does it still proc off of ignite and none damage abilities?

Comment: @ponsfonze Physical damage DOES apply the effects, Piltover Peacemaker will proc spell vamp, Rylai's, Liandry's etc. I am unsure as to the behavior of ignite, but non-damage abilities won't proc because they deal no damage, spell or otherwise.

Comment: @ponsfonze The difference is *SPELL* damage (as in, damage from a spell) as opposed to *MAGIC* damage (as in, purple damage, as opposed to physical's red, and true's white).

Comment: It can also be a combination of all three (e.g. Corki's basic attack with a Wit's End)!

Comment: This kind of seems like a seperate question at this point, "Does Liandry Torment work on Physical damage spells"

Answer (score 1):

If you hover your mouse over the icon of the attack on your death recap, it should tell what is magic damage and what the physical damage is.